# How to execute a MDX Query in Visual studio 2015 using ado.net in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, c#-4.0, ado.net, mdx, olap

net.What I am trying to do is to execute an MDX query using ado.net in Visual studio 2015.Can somebody please refer me the link so that I would able to know how it works.

Apart from that, I need to ask apart from the community that is  ado.net is the only way to execute MDX queries can't I do it using something else.I am using vb.net as a server side language.Please let me know any link or code which would help me.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot information in internet, like [this](http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2011/06/run-mdx-queries-from-net.html) or [that](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6562/Cubes-MDX-Analysis-Services-and-ADOMD-in-C).

C#:

```
using (AdomdConnection conn = new AdomdConnection("Data Source=tfsDB;Initial Catalog=Tfs_Analysis; MDX Compatibility=1;"))
{
    conn.Open();
    var mdxQuery = new StringBuilder();
    mdxQuery.Append("WITH ");
    mdxQuery.Append("SET [Last 4 weeks] as Filter([Date].[Date].[Date], [Date].[Date].CurrentMember.Member_Value < Now() AND [Date].[Date].CurrentMember.Member_Value >= DateAdd(\"d\", - 28, Now())) ");
    mdxQuery.Append("SELECT NON EMPTY Hierarchize(AddCalculatedMembers({DrilldownLevel({[Work Item].[System_WorkItemType].[All]})})) DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME ON COLUMNS , NON EMPTY {Hierarchize(Distinct({[Last 4 weeks]}))} DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS ");
    mdxQuery.Append("FROM (SELECT ({[Work Item].[System_WorkItemType].&[Requirement], [Work Item].[System_WorkItemType].&[Change Request]}) ");
    mdxQuery.Append("ON COLUMNS  FROM [Team System]) WHERE ([Work Item].[Iteration Hierarchy].[All],[Test Case].[System_WorkItemType].[All],[Work Item].[System_State].&[Active],[Measures].[Work Item Count]) ");

    using (AdomdCommand cmd = new AdomdCommand(mdxQuery.ToString(), conn))
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.EnforceConstraints = false;
        ds.Tables.Add();
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        return dt;
    }
}
```

Since I prefer to use Linux on server side, you may check [my blog post](http://blog.soft-prestidigitation.com/ssas-via-python.html) about accessing cubes via Python.

Python:

```
>>> import olap.xmla.xmla as xmla
No handlers could be found for logger "olap.xmla.requests_kerberosauth"
>>> provider = xmla.XMLAProvider()
>>> connect = provider.connect(location='http://localhost/OLAP/msmdpump.dll',username='test_user',password='1234567')
>>> source = connect.getOLAPSource()
>>> print source.getCatalog("TestCube")
XMLACatalog:(row){
CATALOG_NAME = "TestCube"
DESCRIPTION = ""
DATE_MODIFIED = "2016-08-07T09:47:05.026667"
}
```

Comment: They are way too long, I've partly added the code, thanks!

Comment: Yes, I've hit that problem myself with links wondering how I can copy war and peace into my answer but I think what you have done has improved your answer nonetheless. Thanks.